# Specflow feature.cs file throws 'BadImageFormatException' when auto-generating code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

After upgrading to Specflow 2.3.2, feature.cs file generated following error message when changing feature file

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: The module was
>   expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131018)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String
>   path, Evidence evidence)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.CommandLineHandling.PreLoadAssemblies()
>   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.CommandLineHandling.PreLoadAssemblies()
>   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the following setting in visual studio

Tools -> Options -> Specflow (General) -> Generation Mode is selected to 'AppDomain'